# Не удается создать ограничение внешнего ключа в MySql

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

Есть две таблицы. Удалил из них все записи.
И надо создать ограничение внешнего ключа, по полю auth_item::name и modules::main_role_name;
В таблице 2 создаю пытаюсь сделать ограничение внешнего ключа, но выдает ошибку. Хотя оба поля одинакового типа и размера, могут быть NULL, и все записи из обеих таблиц удалены.

```
Ошибка: #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Как посмотреть, по какой причине ключ не создается?
Или какими могут быть причины, если mysql об этом не сообщает?

Сам запрос вот такой:

```
ALTER TABLE `modules` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`main_role_name`) REFERENCES `auth_item`(`name`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Индекс по полю modules::main_role_name стоит.
А поле auth_item::name - оно primary key.

DDL таблиц:

```
| auth_item | CREATE TABLE `auth_item` (
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `rule_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `module_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `main_permission` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `rule_name` (`rule_name`),
  KEY `idx-auth_item-type` (`type`),
  KEY `module_id` (`module_id`),
  KEY `idx-auth_item-main_permission` (`main_permission`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |


| modules | CREATE TABLE `modules` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `orders` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `code` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `main_role_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx-modules-main_role_name` (`main_role_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=91 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT |
```

Comment: Ну а запрос-то, которым создаётся FK - где?

Comment: @Akina отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Отлично. Надеюсь, в структуре таблицы `modules` есть поле `main_role_name`, а в структуре таблицы `auth_item` - индекс по полю `name`?

Comment: @Akina Да, так и есть.

Comment: Выполнение этого же запроса в консоли сервера приводит к той же ошибке или нет? Если да - показывайте DDL таблиц, если нет - пинайте используемую технологию доступа.

Comment: @Akina описал в вопросе

Comment: Определения связываемых полей должны совпадать.

Comment: @Akina имеете ввиду, что в auth_item `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL и в modules `main_role_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL ?

Comment: Ну вот и нашлась причина...

Comment: COLLATION должны ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО совпадать. Что же до размера - если "хвост" за пределами 64 символов неважен для связывания, то можно явно на modules создать индекс на первые 64 символа поля, и использовать именно его для связывания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как написал в комментариях @Akina:

COLLATION должны ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО совпадать. Что же до размера - если "хвост" за пределами 64 символов неважен для связывания, то можно явно на modules создать индекс на первые 64 символа поля, и использовать именно его для связывания.