# Ошибка при создании связи mySQL

Tags: mysql

При попытке создать связь выскакивает ошибка.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718779/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B2-mysql

Comment: Error 1215 имеет всего 5 возможных причин, перечислены в https://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/30.html Для получения доп информации о причине ошибки выполните SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS и смотрите содержимое секции LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR. Используйте для этого консоль, т.к. пхпадмин, емнип, рвет сессию после каждого запроса.

Comment: Вячеслав, перенесите пожалуйста текст ошибки и описание структуры из картинки в текст вопроса. Спасибо.